# Android - Media session/Media buttons in a video player activity (not a service)

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset, android-mediasession

In a video player implemented in an activity, NOT A SERVICE, I am using a MediaSessionCompat to receive media button actions (bluetooth and hset). This video player supports background play, that is the video goeson playing when another activity comes in the foreground.

setActive(true) activates the session and receive media command after the activity 
is launched. My player desativates its media session when the it looses audio focus, not after pausing. Everything is fine up to this point.

If another player (I am testing with VLC) activates request the audio focus and setActive(true) everything works as expected.

But when the user of my app retakes the audio focus by cliking the start button on screen (not with media button), it does not activate the media session and  media button actions are not received.

A media session behaves differently in a service than in an activity but this behaviour seems to contradict android doc which says :

> Android routes media button events in this order: 1) Android first
>   dispatches media button events to the foreground activity (the
>   activity on the screen).

Anyway, could you please help me to reactivate the media session when my app is back on the screen.

Comment: Are you calling setActive(true) again when the user presses play? (I assume so, but you didn't write it.) I also wonder if you're sure the buttons aren't being delivered to the MediaButtonReceiver, or if they're getting dropped somewhere between there and the player?

Comment: I do call setActive(true) again, I do it in onPlayerStateChanged() of Exoplayer. Your second point is precisely my issue. Why buttons are still delivered to the other player after calling setActive(true) in an activity. Again, in a service, setActive(true) works perfectly, I use it in a service in another part of my app. Please also note that if I rotate the mobile (restart the activity) setActive(true) works as expected again. You can see this behaviour in PODCAST CUTTER in the playstore if you like.